# plugin override Joomla MVC not working

Tags: plugins, joomla, overriding

Hellow !

I must use Joomla for a website and I need to override an MVC component (com_contact) to add a field to the contact form. The problem is, I followed this tutorial :

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core/fr

I installed the plugin, rewrote needed files and place them where the tutorial says to place them, but it doesn't work, the plugin is not overidden.

Could someone help me with this please ?

------EDIT---------

I gave up the first tutorial and am now trying to follow this one : 
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla/fr

but my plugin dosen't work. Here is the code of the plugin:

```
/**
 * Prepare form and add my field.
 *
 * @param   JForm  $form  The form to be altered.
 * @param   mixed  $data  The associated data for the form.
 *
 * @return  boolean
 *
 * @since   <your version>
 */

function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
{

    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $option = $app->input->get('option');

    switch ($option) {

        case 'com_contact': {
            if ($app->isAdmin()) {
                JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
                $form->loadFile('item', false);
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
}
?>
```

the contact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="params" label="PLG_CONTENT_EXAMPLE_FIELDSET_LABEL">
        <field
                name="contact_emaillabel2"
                type="text"
                label="PLG_CONTENT_EXAMPLE_CONTACT_EMAILLABEL2"
        />
        <field
                name="contact_email2"
                type="text"
                label="PLG_CONTENT_EXAMPLE_CONTACT_EMAIL2"
                filter="email"
        />
    </fieldset>
</fields>
</form>
```

install xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.2" type="plugin" group="override">
<name>test</name>
<author>Laurine</author>
<creationDate>June 2016</creationDate>
<copyright>Copyright (C) Page Graphique, tous droits réservés</copyright>
<authorEmail>Laurine@page-graphique.fr</authorEmail>
<version>3.2</version>
<description>Plugin pour surcharger les composants MVC</description>
<files>
    <filename>plgoverridetest.php</filename>
</files>
<config>
</config>
</extension>
```

arborescence :

```
- <Joomla>/.../plugins/override
    plgoverridetest.php
    install.xml
    - forms
        contact.xml
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: my code is as said in the tutorial, 
TEMPLATE/code/com_contact/controllers/contact.php
and
TEMPLATE/code/com_contact/models/forms/contact.xml.

Comment: bu I tried many solutions, like putting contact.xml out of forms folder and directly in models folder, put all custom com_contact folder in "html" folder instead of code, putting files out of "controllers" and "models" folders...

Comment: Instead of doing all these you could have simply uploaded another contact component. No need to hack any core files.

Comment: it's sad to add a new component if joomla's one works, I juste need to add one field, and the tutorial is in the documentation, so it should work, maybe I did something wrong, but I can't find what. Furthermore, I already edit the templates of com_contact and I wouldn't like to redo all the works with another form =/

Comment: Thats why I asked you to post your codes so that I can have a look for errors.

Comment: Just so you know, you're using `$app->isAdmin()`, so you plugin code will only be triggered in the admin back-end. If you want it to execute in the front-end, you need to use `!$app->isAdmin()` >> note the `!` at the beginning.

Comment: thanks, I added the "!". But sadly it still doesn't work. As a question, I tried to edit the original files (without override) in joomla and it worked. But if I make an update of Joomla, my code will be replaced or Joomla developpers generally don't edit these files ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link. It will definitely help you https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin.

For site usage you can use

```
case 'com_contact':
    if ($app->isSite())
    {
        JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
        $form->loadFile('contact', false);
    }
    return true;
```

Then you need to edit the template file. Details you can get from that link.

Comment: That's the tutorial I already follow, and I can't get it to work =/

Comment: you're nice but you don't have to do that if you don't have time, I was just wondering where did i go wrong with my plugin ^^

Comment: I think my plugin is not fired, maybe the problem is the name of the class ? I saw many problems with plugin classname

Answer (score 0):

In order to override the contact form, you need to create a 'content' plugin, your plugin above is 'override' so it will not be fired by the contact component.

Also, in your code  `$form->loadFile('item', false);` is wrong because the xml file you're trying to load is 'contact.xml' so your code should be `$form->loadFile('contact', false);`.

I've just completed the development of a plugin that adds many fields such as phone, website, company, file upload, newsletter and includes switching off the default fields if need be. It also sends the information to HubSpot if you use their CRM.

Now the thing is in order to use these extra fields you need to create a 'contact' plugin that's fired when the form is submitted and triggered with the plugin trigger 'onSubmitContact($data)', I've created a 'custom reply' plugin for this purpose.

You need to remember when using a custom reply plugin you must select the 'Custom Reply' option on the contact options in the admin component.

Also, the plugins I've created work on a per form basis rather than having the same fields on multiple forms you can modify each form independently.

Comment: Hi Derek, I am looking to create a plugin to change custom reply. Have you published your plugin on github?

Comment: Hi Edwardo, not as yet, the plan was to create a membership at our site so that we can continue to add more functionality and continue to support the plugin and future development, feel free to drop me an email: derek*at*adonis.media.